# Windows 10 Family Safety: Time limits and screen locking

Tags: windows-10, parental-controls, lock-screen

I recently set up my son's computer with family safety, and I have him limited to 3 hours of total screen time per weekday. I have told him that when he gets up to go outside, eat, or whatever to lock his computer - but it appears that the time he's away is counting toward his total time as well, which defeats the purpose of screen locking IMO. I've scoured Microsoft and the forums to see if screen lock time counts toward computer time in the family safety feature, but have found absolutely nothing. Does anyone out there know for sure, and if so can you post references?
Thanks.

Comment: What is your question exactly?  Do you want us to find an alternate solution that _doesn't_ count lock time as well?  Or do you want us to find evidence that lock time counts towards screen time (which is **off-topic**)?

Comment: The question seems obvious above... does screen lock time count towards Family Safety time (which is **exactly** on topic). Didn't ask for an alternative. Thanks for the edits, BTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI:
Found out after some intensive Googling that lock screen still counts as screen time. After further thought this makes sense because one could have background processes running whilst locked.

Comment: as of now, Windows 8.1 doesn't count the lock screen as screen time

Comment: if you use WinKey-L to lock it

Answer (score 1):

No, the lock screen is not counted as screen time.

It's only when you're logged in that the timer ticks.

Comment: This is contrary to what I have observed in the past. Could Microsoft have changed this feature recently? Can you post a reference?

Comment: This is how it behaves on my computer (which runs Windows 8.1).